# How do I get size of (deb) file from download link/URL?

Tags: apt, wget, size, url

I use `--print-uris` of `apt-get` to get url (download-link) of debs I want to download and install on my Debian ([Trisquel](https://trisquel.info)) GNU/Linux.

```
--print-uris
           Instead of fetching the files to install their URIs are printed. Each URI will have the path, the
           destination file name, the size and the expected MD5 hash. Note that the file name to write to will not
           always match the file name on the remote site! This also works with the source and update commands. When
           used with the update command the MD5 and size are not included, and it is up to the user to decompress any
           compressed files. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Print-URIs.
```

Example output for [`wesnoth`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Battle_for_Wesnoth):-

```
$ apt_uris wesnoth
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/s/sdl-net1.2/libsdl-net1.2_1.2.8-4_i386.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/s/sdl-ttf2.0/libsdl-ttf2.0-0_2.0.11-3_i386.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-data_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-core_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-httt_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-tsg_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-trow_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-ttb_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-ei_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-utbs_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-did_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-nr_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-sof_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-sotbe_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-l_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-aoi_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-thot_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-low_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-dm_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-dw_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth-1.10-music_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/w/wesnoth-1.10/wesnoth_1.10.7-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
```

Note:

```
$ type apt_uris 
apt_uris is a function
apt_uris () 
{ 
    sudo apt-get install "$@" --print-uris -qq | grep http:// | cut -d "'" -f 2;
}
```

Now come to the point:- **I want to get/print size of each deb file from URL** (without downloading).

How do I do that by using `wget` or something else?

Comment: Re-reading this, I take it you missed “Each URI will have the path, the destination file name, **the size** and the expected MD5 hash.” in the help text for `--print-uris` ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical way to get the file size without downloading it would be to issue a HTTP HEAD request and hope for the server to send the size back in the `Content-Length` header. For static files like `deb` files typically, servers are likely to send back that information though there's no guarantee.

There are various tools that can send those HTTP HEAD request. Here's an example of a function that does it using the `curl` utility:

```
get_size() { # arg: URI
  curl -sI "$1" | sed -n 's/^Content-Length: \([0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p'
}
```

Note that it will return that `Content-Length` regardless of whether the query is sucessful or returns with an error (like `404 Not found` where the `Content-Length` will be the size of the error message).

Alternatives to `curl` include:

- GNU `wget`: `wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 --method=HEAD "$1"`. That one will return with a non-success exit status if the query is not-successful (to be used in combination with `set -o pipefail` for instance).
- Perl LWP `HEAD` command: `HEAD "$1"`. That one will also report query failures but follows the HTTP redirections and it doesn't seeem you can disable that.

If it's a human-friendly method you're after, you can also use `lftp` as in:

```
$ lftp -c 'du -h http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/pool/main/s/sdl-net1.2/libsdl-net1.2_1.2.8-4_i386.deb'
12K     /trisquel/pool/main/s/sdl-net1.2/libsdl-net1.2_1.2.8-4_i386.deb
```

Comment: I appreciate use of GNU `wget` which I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

In Debian derivatives the size of each `.deb` file is stored in the list of packages, so you can retrieve it without downloading anything at all.

In fact `apt-get --print-uris` gives you the information directly:

```
$ apt-get install nginx --print-uris -qq
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
'http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/nginx/nginx-common_1.9.1-1_all.deb' nginx-common_1.9.1-1_all.deb 96110 MD5Sum:fc64530dcd5a4d50a36b9f2423fcf6c2
'http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/nginx/nginx-full_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb' nginx-full_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb 471998 MD5Sum:6392f45e4e376ea3be2e60949dd80fe0
'http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/nginx/nginx_1.9.1-1_all.deb' nginx_1.9.1-1_all.deb 75882 MD5Sum:ab5fa732657fba06544b353572967383
```

The third field is the `.deb` file's size.

While I'm at it, you don't need to run `apt-get` as `root` to determine the list of packages to download!